# Eclipse : XML tree or Grid view

Tags: xml, eclipse, editor

I used Eclipse a year back for editing xml file, and had a tree view available.I think I used IDE for Java EE developer then. As part of other development, I installed Eclipse Classic 3.7.2, this time. Through the Help -> Install new software, I installed 1.) Eclipse XML Editors and Tools 2.) Eclipse XSL developer Tools. Even then, I only have a source/textual representation of xml. How to enable tree view?
Also, is there a way to get a grid editor (similar to myeclipse ["Spring Beans Editor - New Grid Mode"](http://www.myeclipseide.com/module-htmlpages-display-pid-17.html))

An ideal setup would be a very minimal eclipse installation intended for xml editing. With support for grid mode, and copy/paste/insert of nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your file associations. Since you started with Eclipse classic it's possible that the file associations that bind the .xml files to the XML editor were not set up. Go to Preferences -> General -> Editor -> File Associations and then select the XML editor which should give you both the text and tree view.

Comment: Also, Eclipse IDE for JavaScript Web Developers, 109 MB was better for in my use case as it is half the size and support xml. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Check JBoss Tools in your Eclipse. I installed Red Hat Jboss Developer Studio 10 from Eclipse Marketplace and I have Tree View to edit web.xml